# How to get real time calculated windows size of a TCP socket

Tags: c++, tcp

I'm running a C++ program on multiple servers. They connect to each other with TCP. I'm running my software on linux.
I'd like to analyze the calculated window size (the real time size) of the sockets.
I've tried TCP_REPAIR_WINDOW, but snd_wnd and rcv_wnd remain constant during the run: 22053;32676
My questions:

1. Do snd_wnd and rcv_wnd represent the real time calculated window size?
2. If yes, why doesn't it change?
3. If no, how can I get this information?
4. How can I get the scaling factor and window size (not the calculated size, which is a factor of the scaling factor) for the socket?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I know enough to strongly suspect that the answer will be  target specific. Do you have an operating system or network stack in mind? If so you should probably add it to the question to improve the focus.

Comment: @user4581301 What's a socket "window size"? The preallocated buffer for incoming messages?

Comment: @MatG Windowing is at both ends. The sender has a window to guard having to stop and wait unnecessarily (`send` usually returns immediately and long before the message actually makes it onto a wire or to the receiver) and the receiver needs to hold information until the client can read it, preferably with minimal wastage copying.

Comment: Are they preallocated? Depends on the strategy used. Usually there 's a pool of resources preallocated and dolled out to sockets as needed. Search key term "Scatter Gather".